# $.get (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html

На странице /php/wnd/index.php?act=read содержится код:

```
<div class='message_wnd'>
 всякий текст
</div>
```

Как можно получить содержимое message_wnd? Мой метод выдаёт **null**:

```
$.get('http://freezly.ru/php/wnd/index.php?act=read', function(data) {
 alert($('.message_wnd', data).html());
});
```

Comment: а чего вы data передаете внутрь селектора как контекст, это же и есть ваш ответ, вставьте его в .html(data)

Comment: alert($('.message_wnd').html(data)); так? Выдаёт [object Object]

Comment: `alert(data.text());`  
Ну это если на странице только этот `div` есть.

Comment: Нет, нужно именно присутствие $('.message_wnd'), так как буду получать последний элемент, посредством :last

Comment: Может что-то типа `data.find('.message_wnd')`?

Comment: 0 эмоций..

Comment: @Руслан Дуров, домен-то ваш? Если нет, ищите crossdomain плагин для jquery) Потому что мне тоже выдало NULL, data = '', status = 0 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если он точно там есть, должно сработать:

```
$.get('http://freezly.ru/php/wnd/index.php?act=read', function(data) {
 alert($('.message_wnd', $(data)).html());
 // или alert($(data).find('.message_wnd').html());
});
```